# cant change attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am simply not able to get to update an attribute of an element using jQuery.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="row1" value="" >
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        // grab name of original
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        // grab value of original
        var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        //check if checked
        if (!ischecked) {
            $('#' + name).removeAttr("checked");
            alert("removed attr ");
        } else {

            $('#' + name).attr("checked", "checked");
            alert($('#' + name).attr("checked"));

        }

    });
});
```

shows up an alert 'undefined' when i check.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly happens?

Comment: # - is for id. you need use [name=yourname] in jquery selectors for finding by name

Comment: `$('#'+name)` which elem has this id? can you post or elaborate it?

Comment: The `checked` state of a checkbox is stored in the `checked` **property**, not the attribute. There should be no reason for you to be setting or removing attributes on that element.

Comment: does it update the html tag attributes too? i want the tag attributes to change cause i have a certain dependency.I get attributes via `attr` later down in the code

Comment: @Nezam You shouldn't be, use the `.prop()` function to get the `checked` property instead.

Comment: thanks for all your responses guys.I will be back in a bit after trying out.Inshallah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong.
You haven´t set an ID to the checkbox. It should look like that:

```
$("input[name='"+name+"']").removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 2):

change `$('#' + name)` to `$(this)`

```
$('#'+name).removeAttr("checked");
```

to

```
$(this).removeAttr("checked");
```

If using jQuery 1.6 or later, you could use

```
$(this).prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: does it update the html tag attributes too? i want the tag attributes to change cause i have a certain dependency.I get attributes via `attr` later down in the code

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this way: [**check the jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/edekey/1/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var value = $(this).val();
    var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");

    if (!ischecked) {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
        alert("removed attr ");
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
        alert($(":checked").val());
    }

  });
});
```

*`shows up an alert 'undefined' when i check.`*

This should be because you are not trying to check the value instead `you can check the length of the **$(':checked')**`

```
alert($(":checked").length);
```

and if you try to check this:

```
alert($(":checked"));
```

You will get `[object object]` in alert.

Comment: does it update the html tag attributes too? i want the tag attributes to change cause i have a certain dependency.I get attributes via `attr` later down in the code

Comment: See if you try something like this you can change the attr anytime in your code.

Comment: does `$(this).prop("checked", true);` translate into `<input type='checkbox' name='row1' checked='checked'>` give me a yes or no

Comment: `$(':checkbox:checked')` gives you all the checked ones.

Comment: Changing the `checked` property is what the browser already does when the `change` event fires, you don't need to do it yourself. In reality what this is going to do is make the checkbox unusable - you'll change it to checked, the change event will fire, and this code will change it back.

Comment: @Nezam I already commented on the question saying this, but it's worth repeating: **do not use the attribute**, use the property instead - you want the `.prop()` function. The `.attr()` function **may** (depending on jQuery version) use the `checked` property anyway, rather than the actual attribute, but don't rely on it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist from what i understand now,that if i use `prop()` instead of `attr()` i don't need to set it like in this answer.Right? because it already gets set when it should.

Comment: this is nice info,thanks all it worked.But,since i got the desired functionality with Vincens ans i am marking that one.

But for all,this solution explains everything.

Comment: @Nezam Yes, if you use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to get the value, you won't need the `change` event handler at all.

Answer (score 0):

'#' works for **id** but not **name**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="row1" id="row1" value="" >
```

or use **this** to get reference.